# Greek letters in cmcsc

Tags: symbols, font-encodings

There is no small caps font available for the math mode. However there are still relevant glyphs with ASCII `0x00` to `0x0a` in `cmcsc`. I wonder what they are and how to TeX them.

Comment: Oops..I meant `0x00`-`0x0a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a math alphabet corresponding to the sc shape and then use `\Gamma` as usual to access the uppercase Greek.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathsc}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{sc}
\begin{document}


$ \mathsc{AaBb\Gamma\Delta} $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, I'm already using `fonttable`. What I don't know is how to TeX the greek letters in `cmcsc`.

Comment: @YingZhou sorry I was just making an example, added to answer now.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please tell me how to use the encoding to type arbitrary glyphs in `cmcsc` as well (i.e. analogous to `\fontfamily{cmtt}\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont\char"0B`)?

Comment: @YingZhou actually the first part of the answer  was written when there was a typo in the hex range in your question, I think i will delete now you have fixed that as it doesn't really make sense now the question is clarified.

Comment: @YingZhou as you see in the arguments to declaremathalphabet it is `\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\fontshape{sc}\selectfont\char"0B`